# Adding ID to StyleSheet link creates HtmlLink tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a simple ID tag to my stylesheet link so that a javascript can manipulate it, but when I do Asp.Net (WebForms, using MasterPage if that matters) creates a HtmlLink tag in the designer automatically? How can I prevent this?

I have this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/skins/css/sidebar-color1.min.css" type="text/css">
```

... and then I add ID:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/skins/mimity/css/sidebar-ash.min.css" id="theme-css" type="text/css">
```

...creates this is the designer:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink
```

Comment: Why would it be an issue if the link was in the designer?

Comment: It crashes the build, since I dont have the runat='server' tag, I guess. And having that might break the javascript (not my own, and may be edited now and then so wanna keep it intact.

Comment: Weird that it crashed the build. I tested it, the id was added to the designer.cs but it did not crash anything... But it should not be a problem if you add runat=server.